# How capture/log api calls (function calls) made by Android app?

Tags: android, api, logging

I have installed an app on AVD (emulator) Android.

Is there a way to get to know the api calls(functions calls) made by the app when I 
play around with it on the AVD(emulator).

Is there a way I can log/capture all the api calls (function calls) made by the app as I interact with it.

Is anybody aware of the tool that captures the flow of the application in terms  of api calls(function calls).

For example if there is a messing app, then typical operations would be

```
[1] launch app
[2] write message
[3] send message

so I want to capture the api calls corresponding to when [1] i.e when the 
app is launched.
then log/capture api calls when [2] i.e write message. finally what api calls were made
when I do [3] i.e hit send button.
```

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: No, please read below comments.

Comment: I think I have found something that may work. Do you have Skype? we can try a few things

Comment: @v09 Did you find any approach that works for you ? Thanks.

Comment: @Arya Was there any approach decided from your discussion with the OP ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all the activity launched by the app in command prompt via :

```
adb logcat | grep "ActivityManager"
```

Comment: Will this work if I don't have source code for the app. I have downloaded some apps from play store(apk). I dont have source code for them

Comment: yup,. launch any app in android and just run this command on ur command prompt the logs will show complete activity flow...

Comment: go to ur command prompt ..type adb devices ..there u can see ur emulator listed ....then run above command and just watch the logs ..it will tell u packagename followed by activity names...

Comment: This will capture only a tiny fraction of the information requested.

Comment: @adcom : Thanks it is a useful tool. But what I am looking is api calls(functions call). Is there a way to get it?

Comment: without code this is what u will get but for api calls u need to watch the logs incase putted by app

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to answer, but I use [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) and it's working great. You can also look into preference values directly from here.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are referring to an App you wrote, you can use the Log class to log messages to logcat.

You can also use the Trace tool to see what's going on in your device and infere the api calls.

Comment: App is not written by me. I am have crawled play store and downloaded apps

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck.  
Even the Trace tool (that lists every method call and it's execution time) needs a debuggable app to connect to.  
If you are reeeeally lucky, the app you are inspecting was uploaded to the PlayStore with the debuggable flag set.

Comment: What if I decompile the app, Does that work? I was thinking of using apktool, dex2jar tools to decompile. But I guess I will end up with lot of errors as these tools doesn't exactly output the source code

Comment: You can use some kind on debugger for Android that let you pause the execution when a code line is executed (if you figure out where your API call is), I have no experience in Android runtime inspection like this.  
I have never used APKtool but you can give it a try and see if you can manage to add the debuggable flag to the manifest. Then you can use the Trace tool.